# How do I delete a sub tree stored in mongodb with parent reference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a a collection which stored tree data as mongo db documents with parent references, as outlined in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/

My question is , how do I delete a node(document) and all the documents under this node(child of child etc) with a mongodb query. I don't want to parse and fetch all the ids and delete them. Is there any mongo mongo query that could help me delete the entire subtree taking the parent reference as the starting param.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: if the answer was helpful please at least give some feedback.

Comment: I was on leave so couldn't test it out. This helps . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to imagine what you're thinking of, but you can run a self $graphLookup, and get the list of documents based on that hierarchy.

You can check an [example I wrote here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BhA8Sqj61ox)

The pipeline is

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    _id: "Books"
  }
},
{
  "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "startWith": "$_id",
    "connectFromField": "_id",
    "connectToField": "parent",
    "as": "ids"
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    "ids": {
      $map: {
        input: "$ids",
        as: "id",
        in: "$$id._id"
      }
    },
    "_id": 0
  }
})
```

Then you just need something like this:

```
db.coll.deleteMany({"_id":{$in:[listHere]}})
```

To that list, you need to add the parent node.